# Error al enviar notificaciones por FCM (Error 401 Authentication Key)

Tags: push-notification, fcm

Estoy creando una aplicación web progresiva para móvil que acepta notificaciones y estoy utilizando Firebase (FCM). Para poder probarla utilizo postman como servidor para el envío de notificaciones a mi aplicación.

Envío a: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

Headers:

```
Authorization: key=SERVER-KEY
Content-Type: application/json
```

Body:

```
{
    "notification": {
        "title": "Hello World",
        "body": "This is Message from Admin"
    },
    "to": "TOKEN-GENERADO"
}
```

Y recibo el siguiente error:

> The request was missing an Authentication Key (FCM Token). Please,
>   refer to section "Authentication" of the FCM documentation, at
>   https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server. Error 401